¿Por qué no me reconoce el método _initialize_platform?
He definido un método _initialize_platform pero no me lo reconoce. ¿Cuál es el problema?
import MetaTrader5 as mt5   
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv


class PlatformConnector():

    def __init__(self):
        
        # Buscamos el archivo .env y cargamos sus valores
        load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

        # Inicialización de la plataforma
        self._initialize_platform()



def _initialize_platform(self) -> None:
    """
    Initializes the MT5 platform.

    Raises:
        Exception: If there is any error while initializing the Platform

    Returns:
        None
    """
    if mt5.initialize(
        path=os.getenv("MT5_PATH"),
        login=int(os.getenv("MT5_LOGIN")),
        password=os.getenv("MT5_PASSWORD"),
        server=os.getenv("MT5_SERVER"),
        timeout=int(os.getenv("MT5_TIMEOUT")),
        portable=eval(os.getenv("MT5_PORTABLE")):
        print("La plataforma MT5 se ha lanzado con éxito")
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Ha ocurrido un error al inicializar la plataforma MT5: {mt5.last_error()}")
    )


Puedes editar la publicación -> eliminar el código -> Copiar el codigo original -> pegarlo -> Seleccionarlo todo -> Darle al boton de { } -> y guardarlo??? Python es muy preciso en cuanto a identacion, por lo que si tienes algun error de esto, necesitamos verlo bien.

Los métodos de una clase deben estar sangrados dentro de la clase. Tal cual lo escribiste, el método _initialize_platform es un método "libre".
class PlatformConnector():

    def __init__(self):

        # Buscamos el archivo .env y cargamos sus valores
        load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

        # Inicialización de la plataforma
        self._initialize_platform()



    def _initialize_platform(self) -> None:
        """
        Initializes the MT5 platform.

        Raises:
            Exception: If there is any error while initializing the Platform

        Returns:
            None
        """
        if mt5.initialize(
            path=os.getenv("MT5_PATH"),
            login=int(os.getenv("MT5_LOGIN")),
            password=os.getenv("MT5_PASSWORD"),
            server=os.getenv("MT5_SERVER"),
            timeout=int(os.getenv("MT5_TIMEOUT")),
            portable=eval(os.getenv("MT5_PORTABLE")):
            print("La plataforma MT5 se ha lanzado con éxito")
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Ha ocurrido un error al inicializar la plataforma MT5: {mt5.last_error()}")
        )

